# How to display column data after first delimiter

Tags: mysql

I have strings with (a random number of) delimiters and I want to display the string after the first delimiter from the left. What is the query for that?

#### Example

I have data values like:

```
DR.V.PRADEEP 
MRS.C.S.PRAMEELA 
MR.V.G. R. PRUDHVI
```

...and I have to display the data after the first "." delimiter, i.e, the output should be:

```
V.PRADEEP
C.S.PRAMEELA
V.G. R. PRUDHVI
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instr` and `substr`. If your table is called `tbl` and the column with the data is called `name`, then it looks like this:

```
select substr(name, instr(name, '.')+1)
from   tbl
```